# Problem with INSERTing to MySQL table, by PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

I creating simple application, first time used PDO, and stuck on
problem...
I searched web for something analogical, but didn't find it.
I cannot insert data into tables. Auto increment value is changing, so
some data are sent to table.
If I echo query with values from variable, copy and paste it to
phpmyadmin, row is inserted properly.
Log contain same query, MySQL and PHP don't return any errors...

Now what I have:

Class article:

```
class article{
    private function findMaxSortId($pdo_object){
        $query_sort="
                    SELECT MAX(sort_id) as max_id
                    FROM articles";
        try{
            $pdo_object->prepare($query_sort);
            $max_row=$pdo_object->query($query_sort)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        catch(PDOException $eSortId){
            $return['error_code_sort']=$eSortId->errorCode();
            $return['error_info_sort']=$eSortId->errorInfo();
        }
        $return['max_id']=$max_row['max_id'];
        return $return;
    }    
    public function createArticle($pdo_object, $title, $body, $visible, $incerase_sort_id=2){
        $return=$this->findMaxSortId($pdo_object);
        $sort_id=$return['max_id']+$incerase_sort_id;

        $pdo_object->exec("
            INSERT INTO `articles` (sort_id, visible, title, body)
            VALUES ('".$sort_id."', '".$visible."', '".$title."', '".$body."')
        ");
        $return['id']=$pdo_object->lastInsertId();
        return $return;
    }
}
```

index.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])&&$_POST['save']=='add'){
    if (isset($_POST['visible'])) {
        $visible=1;
    }
    else{
        $visible=0;
    }
    require_once 'class/class.article.php';
    $art = new article();
    $art->createArticle($pdo, $_POST['title'], $_POST['body'], $visible);
    unset($art);
}
```

articles table in db:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `sort_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `lastmod` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `visible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `title` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `body` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

What I am doing wrong?
Please help.

---

Looks, like problem is more complicated.
I cannot do any operation that write something in DB with PDO.
I can query DB and "read" values, but if i use INSERT or UPDATE, nothing is happening.
I use WampServer 2.1 on 64bit OS.
I can do it without PDO, with mysql query, fetch, etc. ...

Answer (score 3):

You should use prepared statements instead of those crazy query creation code.
Something like:

```
$stmt = $pdo_object->prepare('INSERT INTO `articles` (sort_id, visible, title, body)
            VALUES (:id, :visible, :title, :body)');
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $sort_id,
                     ':visible' => $visible,
                     ':title' => $title,
                     ':body' => $body));
```

It will prevent nasty [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which you don't want.

To see SQL errors you may have, a call to `$pdo_object->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` so it will throw exceptions in case of error. Don't use this like that in a production environment as it gives your database login and password in the exception message.

I'd also advise you to use [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) around your code so you don't have multiple articles using the same sort_id if created at the same moment.

```
public function createArticle($pdo_object, $title, $body, $visible, $incerase_sort_id=2){
  $pdo_object->beginTransaction();
  try{
    $return=$this->findMaxSortId($pdo_object);
    $sort_id=$return['max_id']+$incerase_sort_id;

    $stmt = $pdo_object->prepare('INSERT INTO `articles` (sort_id, visible, title, body)
                VALUES (:id, :visible, :title, :body)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $sort_id,
                         ':visible' => $visible,
                         ':title' => $title,
                         ':body' => $body));
    $return['id']=$pdo_object->lastInsertId();
  }catch(Exception $e){
    $pdo_object->rollBack();
    return null;
  }
  $pdo_object->commit();
  return $return;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried prepared statements, result is same. But i tried it with question marks.
I will check it and let You know. I will check also ERRMODE.

Thanks for advice with transactions i will use it in other project, but as i wrote this project is simple, there will be 10-15 articles, so it will be sorted once and for all, i think ;)
This will be website where i put other website XML affiliate program specification (XML, implementation, etc). I will modify it probably once for 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
    $pdo_object->exec("
        INSERT INTO `articles` (sort_id, visible, title, body)
        VALUES (`".$sort_id."`, `".$visible."`, `".$title."`, `".$body."`)
    ");
```

You should replace backticks with single or double quotes:

```
    $pdo_object->exec("
        INSERT INTO `articles` (sort_id, visible, title, body)
        VALUES ('".$sort_id."', '".$visible."', '".$title."', '".$body."')
    ");
```

Backticks are to be used for table and field names.

Comment: @Jon Stirling & sanmai you are right, but this is result of my combinations ;) quotes was first option and in this form i should post code, but i changed it many times and just forgot to change it back

Comment: I just changed those backticks to quotes. Just to not mislead others.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the backticks from the INSERT INTO with quotes when dealing with values.